# How to create a copy file Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I get the file:

```
  $fileExcel = Storage::path($finreport->filename);
```

How to creat a copy file and place in the same directory with prefix name _copy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First google answer: use File facade

```
File::copy($fileExcel, $copyPath);
```

for the file name you can explode, implode the path

```
$array = explode('.', $fileExcel);
$index = count($array) != 1 ? count($array) - 2 : 0;
$array[$index] = $array[$index].'_copy';
$copyPath = implode('.', $array);
```

Comment: Yes, I tried, how to specify the same path for $copyPath?

Comment: @MeganClerc edited the answer to give you an example of how you can name the copy

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Storage, to keep it consistent you might want to use

```
Storage::copy('old/file.jpg', 'new/file.jpg');
```

If you're wanting to prefix you can do something like

```
Storage::copy("old/$finreport->filename", "old/copy_$finreport->filename");
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#copying-moving-files